# Improve location using multiple gps coordinates

Tags: triangulation

Given two or more gps coordinates, is it possible to improve the accuracy of the target location?  Would there be a minimum number of coordinates required?  Would there be a upper limit to the number of coordinates at which the accuracy would stop improving or improve only marginally?

Comment: The problem is simple with $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ coordinates; have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583576/triangulating-gps-coordinates $3$ is a minimum. More you have, more accurate.

Comment: The error in GPS coordinates is correlated among different receivers as it depends on atmospheric distortion of the signals and on incorrect estimates of the satellites' position. So Having more than one GPS sensor in the same position gives little improvement.